Is there a way to inject or install a plugin/reporter at runtime without affecting the dev environment?
I am working on an extension for vscode and have everything working for what I want to do, except for one thing. Unfortunately, this one thing is the whole point of the extension. In essence, what I am trying to do is register a custom reporter with karma from within the extension so that I can get the results of each spec.
Ordinarily, this would look like:
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(/* new reporter constructor */);

Now, obviously I can't exactly do that because the extension would have a completely separate environment from the workspace.
I have tried everything I can think of including adding arguments to the command that is run like so:
module.exports = function (config) {
   reporters: ["progress", "kjhtml"],
}

import { exec } from "node:child_process";

// extra code related to building the command
const args = ["npm", "test", "--", "--reporters=progress,kjhtml,spec"]
exec(args.join(" "))

Unfortunately, if I try to add a reporter to that list while it isn't found, it does the very obvious thing of throwing an error stating that the reporter couldn't be loaded because it isn't registered.
Can anyone think of a way to register a reporter with jasmine externally?
